# Prohibit escaping to the web from the Google Sign-In dialog

Tags: ios, google-signin

When using 'Google Sign-In' (either via an official SDK such as the iOS SDK, or manually by popping up a browser view with the authorization page URL), there are ways to escape the sign-in view, and go to Google and search/browse the web (e.g. by clicking the "Privacy" link, scrolling to the bottom, and clicking the "Google" link)

I have an (iOS) app where I would like to just use Google for sign-in, but not give my users access to the web. Is there a way to lock down the Google Signin dialog to have this?

Comment: Why are you spending precious time on that? What are you afraid users might do?

Comment: @luk2302 Cheating on an exam they take in my app

Comment: And you want to disable the home button as well? What if they activate Siri during the test and ask it to google something? Is the sign-in form displayed during the test, not before?

Comment: @luk2302 All these things are under control of the OS, and can be locked down. The sign in view is external, and cannot.

Comment: Ah, you are building sort of a „kiosk application“!?